# Excluding part of a npm package from a claudia.js build

Tags: node.js, lambda, serverless, claudiajs

I'm currently using `claudia.js` to deploy serverless functions to AWS Lambda. However, due to size limitations I run into the following error:

> RequestEntityTooLargeException: Request must be smaller than 69905067 bytes for the CreateFunction operation

To resolve this, I'm trying to exclude a subfolder of a npm package as it's not needed, but I'm unsure how to do this during the `claudia build` process.

Specifically, I'd want to exclude an example subfolder > `node_modules/packet/subfolder/*`

I've messed around with various configurations of `.gitignore` and `.npmignore` but with little success. Any help would be amazing!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing that you can simply use `--use-s3-bucket` option with Claudia.js and 50mb limit will be increased to 250mb (uncompressed).

Try running the following command:

`claudia update --use-s3-bucket BUCKET_NAME --region YOUR_REGION`

Where `BUCKET_NAME` is a name of the deployment helper bucket in the same region (`YOUR_REGION`).